# X-Forwarded-For header with ipv4 server called by ipv6 client

Tags: dns, ipv6, nat, ipv4

i have a question regarding to the X-Forwarded-For header / ipv4 server called by ipv6 client.

If the server receives a request, that was transferred by NAT64/DNS64, will the  X-Forwarded-For headers remains the same (IPv6)?

does that mean that every service (using this header) needs to adapt to the new protocol?

cheers

Answer (score 5):

NAT64 does not add an X-Forwarded-For header because it works at layer 3&4 (IP&TCP) and doesn't change the application data at layer 7 (HTTP). X-Forwarded-For is added by reverse proxies, which will indeed show the IPv6 address of the client.